# post_save seams has bug

Tags: django, django-signals

my simplified problem is below:

i have a model like this:

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    ALERT_CHOICES = [("email","email"),("sms","sms"),("notif","notif")]
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coins = models.ManyToManyField(Coin,blank=True)
```

when an object of Alert like alert changes. i want to print number of coins that connected to alert after change in this method:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Alert)
def handle_alert_save(sender, instance,  **kwargs):
    coins = instance.coins.all()
    print(len(coins))
```

**Unfortunately!** it prints number of coin before change alert. i want after change the object.
in other words post_save signal is exactly equal to pre_save.

**for example** when i have 2 connected coin to aler and i change it to 5. it prints 2!

i try all other signals like pre_save and pre_delete and pre_migrate and post_migrate.

Comment: No, it does trigger the signal *after* saving the `Alert`, but the many-to-many fields are saved *after* saving the `Alert`, so at that time, there are indeed still no coins updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does trigger the signal *after* saving the `Alert`, but the many-to-many fields are saved *after* saving the `Alert`, so at that time, there are indeed still no coins updated. This is one of the [*many* reasons not to use signals in the first place <sup>[django-antipatterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html).

You could use the [**`m2m_changed`** signal <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) instead:

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed


@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Alert.coins.through)
def handle_alert_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    coins = instance.coins.all()
    print(len(coins))
```

But personally, I think signals are often not a good idea and should be used as last resort. It might be more robust to simply add a function to do the logic, and trigger this in the views where you alter the `.coins` of an `Alert` instance.

Comment: thanks for your attention. but this is not my desired response. this method prints length of coins before and after. i want just after

Comment: @HosseinSayyedmousavi: it is *after*, but saving the `Alert` will *not* save the coins, since one first needs a primary key before you can link items in the many-to-many field. Therefore a form for example will call `instance.save()` and then `form.save_m2m()` so the signal is triggered after saving the *`Alert`*, not the many-to-many field in that `Alert` model.

Comment: what is your proposal? i want to get number of coins after save that. can i use other field? or over ride other class methods?

Comment: @HosseinSayyedmousavi: as said, you can use the `m2m_changed` signal. This will be triggered each time the m2m relation changes. In fact it is possible that the m2m changes *without* the `Alert` being saved, since that is, strictly speaking, a different model (the junction model between `Alert` and `Coin`).

Comment: as i said before this is simplified problem. i have 2 ManyToManyField attribute in my class the second one is "strategies". and i want to have 3 signal to handle some events:

1) when alert changes:
means when i connect it to a coin or strategy
2)when each coins of this alert changes
means when a coin changes not connected from an alert
3)when each strategies of this alert changes
means when a strategy changes not connected from an alert

Comment: @HosseinSayyedmousavi: well, then the latter is `@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Alert.strategies.through)` for changing strategies. So you can define three signals for each of the events. But again, signals are often not a good idea: have some caveats when they do (not) run, make the logic unpredictable, etc.

Comment: Thank you. my problem has solved. i use m2m_changed and actions to find fields of foreign keys